# Uploading a file in VB to a Web Service

Tags: html, vb.net, web

Ok, firstly let me say that accessing web services is whole new game for me, I have next to no knowledge of this side of things.
I have a need to write a small app to enable a user to upload a file to a nominated web service and really have no idea of what is required. I have cobbled together some code (see below) that I have sampled from various places, it runs, but it does not upload the file. I suspect that I am connecting to the web service, as I am no longer receiving Access Denied errors :)
Any help on getting the correct code to upload the file would be appreactiated.

```
Private Sub Process_XML(ByVal strXML As String, ByVal strStatus As String)
    Dim UserCredentials As NetworkCredential
    Dim strTestUrl As String = "https://webservice.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/LodgeDRS.wsdl"

    Try
      'ok, setup credentials for authentication
      UserCredentials = New NetworkCredential("FGS243_WS", "xxxxxxxxxx")

      Select Case strStatus
        Case "TEST"
          UploadXML(strTestUrl, UserCredentials)
        Case "PRODUCTION"
      End Select
    Catch ex As Exception
      Error_Message("Process_XML")
    End Try
  End Sub

  Private Sub UploadXML(ByVal uriName As String, ByVal creds As NetworkCredential)
    Try
      ' get the file name from the path
      Dim strFile As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strXMLFileName)

      ' get the file information for the selected file
      Dim fInfo As New FileInfo(strXMLFileName)

      ' get the length of the file to see if it is possible
      ' to upload it (with the standard 4096 kb limit)
      Dim numBytes As Long = fInfo.Length
      Dim dLen As Double = Convert.ToDouble(fInfo.Length / 1000000)

      ' look for an overrun on file size
      If (dLen < 5) Then
        ' set up a filestream and binary reader for the file
        Dim fStream As New FileStream(strXMLFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim br As New BinaryReader(fStream)

        ' convert the file to a byte array
        Dim FileData As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(numBytes))
        br.Close()

        Dim myHttpWebRequest As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(uriName), HttpWebRequest)
        myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml"
        myHttpWebRequest.Method = "POST"
        myHttpWebRequest.Credentials = creds
        myHttpWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = True

        Dim myHttpWebResponse As HttpWebResponse = CType(myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

        Dim receiveStream As Stream = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()
        Dim encode As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
        Dim readStream As New StreamReader(receiveStream, encode)
        Dim strResponse As String = readStream.ReadToEnd()
        readStream.Dispose()
        receiveStream.Dispose()

        Console.Write(strResponse)
        Console.ReadLine()

        fStream.Close()
        fStream.Dispose()
        MsgBox("Done")
      Else
        MsgBox("The file selected, " & strXMLFileName & ", exceeds the size limit for uploads")
      End If
    Catch ex As Exception
      Error_Message("UploadXML")
    End Try
  End Sub
```

Comment: Think you might of mixed up some of the examples you've been looking at.  The will needs to go as part of myHttpWebRequest, The myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream() part would be more for downloading files

Comment: I dont doubt that I have mixed things up. As I said this is all very new to me. Thanks for the pointer ....

Answer (score 0):

In a recent surveying you did, you observed some points which are the vertices of a parcel of land. Create an input file in a location in your system to store the observed points. The input file must be in the format below:
PL1              E1     N1
PL2     E2      N2
PL3     E3      N3
PL4     E4      N4
.       .       .
.       .       .
.       .       .
PLn     En      Nn

From the file created above, read the data and generate an output file stored in the same folder as the input file that shows the distances  and bearings of each of the consecutives pillars.
The output file must be in the following format:

Names:      XXXX   YYYY ZZZZZ
Matric No:  999999999999999
Class:      PD12022/2023
Course: Computer Programming & Application

Back Computation

---

From        Change in E     Change in N     Distance    Bearing To

---

PL1         -           -        -             -                PL2
PL2         -           -        -             -                PL3
PL3         -           -        -             -                PL4
PL4         -           -        -             -                PL5
PL5         -           -        -             -                PL6
.           .           .                  .               .        .
.           .           .                  .               .        .
.           .           .                  .               .        .

PLn-1           -           -        -             -                PLn

---

Note: You must have at least at least 15 observed points

Important:
To Submit:
Code Listing
Input files (Q1 and Q2)
Output files (Q1 and Q2)
Presentation Mode: Individual with coding system along
Submission: 2 weeks after the exams